# Generating complete lists of polynomials

Tags: list-manipulation, polynomials, expression-construction

I would like to generate a list of all $3$-variable Laurent polynomials with non-negative integer coefficients using a looping construct so that I can, one-by-one, check them for specific specializations.

**Of course, by "all" I mean "all within certain bounds", e.g. on the coefficients, exponents, number of terms... so long as these bounds can be flexibly changed.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

**Sample input/output**:
Say we want to produce all ordinary (vs. Laurent) polynomials with non-negative integer coefficients in two variables `x`,`y`, subject to:
Maximum coefficient is $2$
Maximum `x` and `y` exponents are $1$

Input> 
`{2,1,1}`

Output> 
`0`,
`1`,
`2`,
`x`,
`1+x`,
`2+x`,
`2x`,
`1+2x`,
`2+2x`,
`y`,
`1+y`,
`2+y`,
`2y`,
`1+2y`,
`2+2y`,
`x+y`,
`1+x+y`,
`2+x+y`,
`2x+y`,
`1+2x+y`,
`2+2x+y`,
`x+2y`,
`1+x+2y`,
`2+x+2y`,
`2x+2y`,
`1+2x+2y`,
`2+2x+2y`,
`xy`,
`1+xy`,
`2+xy`,
`x+xy`,
`1+x+xy`,
`2+x+xy`,
$\ldots$,
`2+2x+2xy+2y`

for a total of $3^4 = 81$ items in the list.  Note that they do not need to be produced in any particular order.

Again, the "output" should be produced via a loop or otherwise, so that I can perform some analysis on one item of the list and then either "terminate" or move to the next item on the list.

For this simplified example, an input of `{a,b,c}` will produce a list with $(a+1)^{(b+1)(c+1)}$ items.

Comment: Please give an example of the *input* and *output* that you desire.

Comment: Sure. I've included a simplified example in the original post.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I propose this:

```
poly[C_, exp_, var_] :=
  Times @@@ Tuples[var^Range[0, exp]] //
    Tuples[Range[0, C], Length @ #].# &
```

Test:

```
poly[2, {1, 1}, {x, y}] // Sort // Short
```

> ```
> {0, 1, 2, x, 2 x, 1+x, <<69>>, x+2 y+2 x y, 1+x+2 y+2 x y, 2+x+2 y+2 x y,
>  2 x+2 y+2 x y, 1+2 x+2 y+2 x y, 2+2 x+2 y+2 x y}
> ```

This is also much faster than `lp`:

```
lp[1, {3, 2}, {x, y}]   // Timing // First
poly[1, {3, 2}, {x, y}] // Timing // First
```

> ```
> 0.327
>
> 0.015
> ```

Allowing even:

```
poly[2, {3, 2}, {x, y}] // Length // Timing
```

> ```
> {2.886, 531441}
> ```

### Extension to massive sets

Although not requested here is an approach for extending this code to larger sets.  Since huge sets will consume too much memory we could use an incremental approach, relying on [`IntegerDigits`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/IntegerDigits.html) to construct the `Dot` vectors one at a time.  Although this would make generating an entire series slower it allows exploration within a series.

```
mem : poly[C_, exp_, var_, "VEC"] := mem =  (* memoization *)
  Times @@@ Tuples[ var^Range[0, exp] ] // {Length @ #, #} &

poly[C_, exp_, var_, part_] :=
  IntegerDigits[part - 1, C + 1, #].#2 & @@ poly[C, exp, var, "VEC"]
```

Now we can look at e.g. the 5,141,324,824th polynomial in this sequence:

```
poly[3, {4, 1, 2}, {x, y, z}, 5141324824]
```

> ```
> x^3 + x^4 + 3 x^2 y + 2 x^3 y + x^4 y + x^2 z + 3 x^3 z + x^3 y z + x^4 y z + 
>  2 x^2 y z^2 + 2 x^3 y z^2 + 3 x^4 y z^2
> ```

Or a list of polynomials in a smaller sequence:

```
poly[2, {1, 1, 3}, {x, y, z}, {997, 998, 999}] // Column
```

> ```
> x z + 2 x y z + x z^2 + 2 x y z^2
> x z + 2 x y z + x z^2 + 2 x y z^2 + x y z^3
> x z + 2 x y z + x z^2 + 2 x y z^2 + 2 x y z^3
> ```

Memoization of the terms vector is included to speed sampling in truly *massive* sets:

```
poly[17, {14, 35, 137}, {x, y, z}, 22]
poly[17, {14, 35, 137}, {x, y, z}, 1341]
poly[17, {14, 35, 137}, {x, y, z}, 7^14913] // LeafCount
```

> ```
> x^14 y^35 z^136 + 3 x^14 y^35 z^137
>
> 4 x^14 y^35 z^135 + 2 x^14 y^35 z^136 + 8 x^14 y^35 z^137
>
> 102378
> ```

Comment: @Mr.Wizard...thanks for timings as well...(and much faster as well as neater and clearer)...one day will learn how to be more efficient...

Comment: @ubpdqn You're welcome, and thanks for being gracious.

Comment: @ubpdqn Sorry to keep hammering on your code, but since you're open to comments, it looks like my method is also about ten times more memory efficient.

Comment: I am very grateful. I will edit my answer to look at your answer. I am grateful that the seeds of the idea are the same (tuples of components and coefficients and assembling...I hadn't appreciated how nice Range and Tuples would work...the inner product was what I wanted to get to but 'bailed' with use of `CoefficientRules` construct.

Comment: very nice using padded base representation (`IntegerDigits`) to convert element index to vector. However, should it be `IntegerDigits[part - 1, C + 1, #]`. As, e.g. for the 81 polynomials of orginal test case: they go from 1 to 81 <-> {0,0,0,0}->{2,2,2,2} (<=>54+18+6+2=80=81-1)?

Comment: @ubpdqn I think you're right!  Time to fix that.

Comment: Thanks again for helping me out with this.  I am now trying to cut down computation time by limiting the "list" to only relevant polynomials with certain properties.  In particular, the relevant polynomials will be Laurent polynomials (they include negative exponents) with the property that they are symmetric with respect to inversion of the variables.  For example `x^(-1) + 1 + x` is symmetric with respect the transformation $x\mapsto x^{-1}$.  How might I implement this?

Comment: @Ross I suggest you post a new question, referencing this one.

Answer (score 4):

**EDIT**

See [Mr. Wizard's answer](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/47297/1997) (better in terms of conciseness, efficiency and memory usage).

My original answer:

Does this achieve your desired result:

```
lp[r_, exp_, var_] := Module[{num, tup, v},
  num = Times @@ (1 + exp);
  tup = Tuples[Range[0, r], num];
  v = Flatten[Outer[List, ##], Length@exp - 1] & @@ (Range[0, #] & /@ 
      exp);
  FromCoefficientRules[#, var] & /@ (Thread[v -> #] & /@ tup)
  ]
```

where `r` is the range of integer coefficients, `exp` is the list of exponents and `var` is the variable names.

So your example:

```
lp[2, {1, 1}, {x, y}]
```

yields 81 polynomials:

```
{0, x y, 2 x y, x, x + x y, x + 2 x y, 2 x, 2 x + x y, 2 x + 2 x y, y,
  y + x y, y + 2 x y, x + y, x + y + x y, x + y + 2 x y, 2 x + y, 
 2 x + y + x y, 2 x + y + 2 x y, 2 y, 2 y + x y, 2 y + 2 x y, x + 2 y,
  x + 2 y + x y, x + 2 y + 2 x y, 2 x + 2 y, 2 x + 2 y + x y, 
 2 x + 2 y + 2 x y, 1, 1 + x y, 1 + 2 x y, 1 + x, 1 + x + x y, 
 1 + x + 2 x y, 1 + 2 x, 1 + 2 x + x y, 1 + 2 x + 2 x y, 1 + y, 
 1 + y + x y, 1 + y + 2 x y, 1 + x + y, 1 + x + y + x y, 
 1 + x + y + 2 x y, 1 + 2 x + y, 1 + 2 x + y + x y, 
 1 + 2 x + y + 2 x y, 1 + 2 y, 1 + 2 y + x y, 1 + 2 y + 2 x y, 
 1 + x + 2 y, 1 + x + 2 y + x y, 1 + x + 2 y + 2 x y, 1 + 2 x + 2 y, 
 1 + 2 x + 2 y + x y, 1 + 2 x + 2 y + 2 x y, 2, 2 + x y, 2 + 2 x y, 
 2 + x, 2 + x + x y, 2 + x + 2 x y, 2 + 2 x, 2 + 2 x + x y, 
 2 + 2 x + 2 x y, 2 + y, 2 + y + x y, 2 + y + 2 x y, 2 + x + y, 
 2 + x + y + x y, 2 + x + y + 2 x y, 2 + 2 x + y, 2 + 2 x + y + x y, 
 2 + 2 x + y + 2 x y, 2 + 2 y, 2 + 2 y + x y, 2 + 2 y + 2 x y, 
 2 + x + 2 y, 2 + x + 2 y + x y, 2 + x + 2 y + 2 x y, 2 + 2 x + 2 y, 
 2 + 2 x + 2 y + x y, 2 + 2 x + 2 y + 2 x y}
```

3 variable case yields 6561:

```
lp[2, {1, 1, 1}, {x, y, z}]
```

[image]

Comment: Perfect.  Thanks a million!

Comment: You have my vote, but see my answer for how this might be done considerably faster.

Comment: @RossElliot Mr.  Wizard's  answer is the better answer...see commentary