# Efficient way to make subsets of list with placeholders

Tags: list-manipulation, combinatorics, subset

I have an arbitrary list of unique elements:

```
lst = {a, b, c, d}
```

Documentation allows finding subsets with same number of elements, say `2`:

```
Subsets[lst, {2}]
(* {{a, b}, {a, c}, {a, d}, {b, c}, {b, d}, {c, d}} *)
```

What I need is to add some placeholder, i.e. `0`, to each subset.

> `{{a, b, 0, 0}, {a, 0, c, 0}, {a, 0, 0, d}, {0, b, c, 0}, {0, b, 0, d}, {0, 0, c, d}}`

Replacements work slow (even freeze) for large lists and many subsets.

```
lst /. # & /@ (Thread[# -> 0] & /@ Complement[list, #] & /@ Subsets[lst, {2}])
```

I'd like to have a better way.

(Application - intertemporal choice problems with discrete time).

Comment: So, `ReplacePart[ConstantArray[0, Length[lst]], Thread[# -> lst[[#]]]] & /@ Subsets[Range[Length[lst]], {2}]` doesn't work for you?

Comment: Another option `Normal@SparseArray[
    MapThread[First@Position[lst, #] -> # &, Transpose@{#}]
    , Length@lst
    ] & /@ Subsets[lst, {2}]`, pretty similar to J.M.'s solution, but you can keep it in sparse form to save some memory for large lists. i.e. remove `Normal` if you want.

Comment: Another way to do @N.J.'s idea: `SparseArray[Flatten[MapIndexed[Map[Function[k, Append[#2, k] -> lst[[k]]], #1] &, Subsets[Range[Length[lst]], {2}]]]]`.

Comment: You guys know that answer's field is below?

Comment: @Kuba, I wanted the OP to test the damn things first before committing to an answer. "Replacements work slow (even freeze) for large lists" made me ask if the replacement-based method I gave would also be inappropriate.

Comment: Related: [(5036)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/5036/121),  [(62888)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/62888/121), [(82801)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/82801/121).  More distantly related, but since you (garej) seem to like reading my code you might find this entertaining: [(47285)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/47285/121)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Depending on your Mma version:

```
{a, b, c, d} # & /@ Permutations[{1, 1, 0, 0}]
```

Or

```
<< Combinatorica`

{a, b, c, d} # & /@ Combinatorica`Permutations[{1, 1, 0, 0}]
(*{{a, b, 0, 0}, {a, 0, c, 0}, {a, 0, 0, d}, {0, b, c, 0}, {0, b, 0, d}, {0, 0, c, d}}*)
```

Comment: ``Combinatorica`Permutations[{1, 1, 0, 0}]`` is not working here, in 10.2 -- can you think of a reason I'm forgetting?

Comment: @Mr.Wizard Nope. Perhaps they renamed/ghosted some Combinatorica functions to prevent name clashing?

Comment: Default `Permutations[{1, 1, 0, 0}]` works OK here too.

Comment: @Mr.Wizard Ok, thanks. Answer updated

Comment: This appeared to be most robust in different scenarious (in some general form that calculates the permutation lists).

Answer (score 8):

Not the smartest, but working:

```
GroupBy[
  Tuples@Thread[{lst, 0}],
  Count[0]
  ][2] (*here 2 is length @ lst - 2*)
```

> ```
> {{a, b, 0, 0}, {a, 0, c, 0}, {a, 0, 0, d}, {0, b, c, 0}, {0, b, 0, d}, {0, 0, c, d}}
> ```

or

```
Function[lst,
 ReplacePart[0 lst, #] & /@ MapThread[
     Rule, Subsets[#, {2}] & /@ {Range@Length@lst, lst}, 2
 ]
]
```

The second method is 2000x times and MaxMemoryUsed is around 150KB in comparison to 500MB of the first one.

Comment: looks good, and smart :))

Comment: Somehow, `Tuples[]` looks to me like it would consume more memory than `Subsets[]`...

Comment: @J.M. That's why I put a comment.

Comment: @J.M. added something more efficient

Answer (score 6):

```
Normal@({a, b, c, d} SparseArray[ # -> 1 & /@ #, 4]) & /@ 
 Subsets[Range[4], {2}]
```

> {{a, b, 0, 0}, {a, 0, c, 0}, {a, 0, 0, d}, {0, b, c, 0}, {0, b, 0, 
>     d}, {0, 0, c, d}}

Comment: `Normal @ ({a, b, c, d} SparseArray[Thread[# -> 1], 4]) & /@ 
 Subsets[Range[4], {2}]` is equivalent. Another possibility is `Normal @ SparseArray[Thread[# -> {a, b, c, d}[[#]]], 4] & /@ Subsets[Range[4], {2}]`.

Answer (score 3):

Taking the idea from Mr.Wizard [answer](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/104085/replicate-and-expand-a-list/104098#104098)

```
rules = Join[Thread[# -> #], {_ -> 0}] & /@ Subsets[lst, {2}];
Replace[lst, #, 1] & /@ rules
```

Or

```
Lookup[Thread[#->#],lst,0]&/@Subsets[lst,{2}]
```

Comment: I wouldn't have thought to use this method here. +1 for expanding my thinking. :-)

Comment: @Mr.Wizard your thoughts always inspire me. You don't imagine how much I learn from you:-)